# 404 Not Found [IP: 193.1.193.69 80] when running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Getting this error when trying to upgrade

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/libgtk-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb  
404  Not Found [IP: 193.1.193.69 80]
```

I've tried `sudo aptitude update` and `sudo aptitude autoclean`, as suggested in similiar questions, but they haven't helped.

```
rob@laptop:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade``

```
rob@laptop:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386 libstartup-notification0:i386 libxcb-util0:i386 mksh pdksh
  t1-xfree86-nonfree wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  standalone-productivity-layer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcanberra-gtk3-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386 libcolord1:i386
  libgtk-3-0:i386 libjpeg62 libnotify1:i386 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0:i386 notification-daemon:i386
  productivity-layer wine-gecko2.34 wine-gecko2.34:i386 wine-mono4.5.4
The following packages will be upgraded:
  full-layer libqt5gui5 wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386
5 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,919 kB/816 MB of archives.
After this operation, 569 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgtk-3-0 i386 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.1.193.69 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/libgtk-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.1.193.69 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

libgtk-3-0 i386 has been updated from 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2 to 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3. Running the `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0:i386` command may succeed in fetching the libgtk-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1_i386.deb file from your default repositories.

If that doesn't work, you can find the download page for the updated version of libgtk-3-0:i386 [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgtk-3-0/download). After you have downloaded the libgtk-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1_i386.deb file, double click on it to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.